# Split long string on ">

Tags: java, regex, coldfusion, split

I'm trying to use `split()` method to split long string containing repeated tags (content of a text document containing CFML code), each of which terminates with those 2 chars: `">` and a line break.

I cannot figure out how to accomplish that, was trying multiple regexes with no luck, inside of mentioned tags there can be nested other tags ( please don't ask why :-) ), and the split breaks on those nested tags, even if they do not contain `">`

Example:

```
<cfset code = "Text text text <table style='width:538px; [... more text stripped ...] </table>">
<cfset another_code = "Text text text">
...
```

Any clues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using regex have you tried an XML parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it with pure regex, I would use `str.split(Pattern.quote("\">"))`.

However, you should consider using an XML parser such as SAX, StAX, DOM parser, etc. There's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You are absolutely right, in both parts of your answer! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are you trying to do but if you want to split on `">(new line)` then maybe use `split("\">\r?\n")`. But maybe you want to split on new line mark that has `">` before? In that case you can use look-behind mechanism like `split("(?<=\">)\r?\n")`

Comment: This is very interesting, although @WChargin 's method worked for me. Shouldn't `split("\">\r?\n)` be `split("\">\r?\n")`?

Comment: @Jacek yes, I was typing without compiling and forgot about quotation mark :)